# How to organize a pseudo streaming by using splited file (chunked file)?

Tags: video, nginx, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264

I have chunks of an mp4 file. Each chunk 2 seconds. I have to organize a pseudo streaming by using these chunks. It is easy to organize a pseudo streaming with one whole mp4 file but I have to store chunks (each 2 seconds).
Somebody know if it possible to organize a pseudo streaming chunks of the file by using NGINX, Nimble Streamer or other free media server? (Not a streaming like HLS or DASH but an mp4 pseudo streaming).

Comment: You could write your own javascript client using the HTML5 Media Source Extensions to download each chunk and then append them in the client before passing them to the HTML5 player, but it would be a lot of work and probably easier to just use one of the open source streaming servers.

Comment: Of Course it is easier to use a free streaming server but I can't find how to configure something like Nginx or Nimble Streamer to use video chunks.
Also I don't understand how to make a pseudo streaming with MSE  because I have only chunks of the video I haven't the whole video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of pre-packaged files, there are 2 basic forms of streaming:

1. Progressive download which uses whole file (not split) to show it in any PD-capable player. E.g. all browsers capable of HTML5 video tag have support for it.
2. HLS/DASH/HDS/Smooth protocols which use a playlist and a bunch of chunks. A player gets a playlist and then downloads chunks as long as it's needed for playback. Those chunks must be pre-formatted in the way the player could decode them properly, this means HLS chunks won't be played by HDS player for example.

You have some "middle case" where you want to use option 1 while having content for option 2. So you need to decide whih option you want to proceed with.
I would recommend composing those chunks into single MP4 files for option 1. It will also make it available for easy transmuxing into HLS, MPEG-DASH or whatever you decide to use later.